# Deprecated debug package:

Tags: symfony, debugging, symfony4, handler, deprecated

I have found a PHP Notice in the logs:
[info] User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler" instead.

This code is invoked from **Vendor** folder, so I have been checking what package is using this package. I have found that the package symfony/monolog-bundle is the problem.
I am using:

- https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/monolog-bundle#v3.6.0
- It requires: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-kernel#v4.3.11
- It requires the problematic package: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/debug

I have been trying to upgrade the package http-kernel to a newest version which not using symfony debug, it means from http-kernel>v5.0

I am executing this code and receiving this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Pablo-Garces:cp-igw pgarces$ composer require "symfony/error-handler:5.0.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/error-handler
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/http-kernel[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.18] require symfony/error-handler ^4.4 -> found symfony/error-handler[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.18] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (5.0.*).
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/http-kernel ^4.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.18].
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It looks like you have a Symfony 4.4 app? If so, trying to upgrade just one component to 5.0 will not work.  I have seen a few questions on this.  Are you sure there are no other third party bundles that might be triggering this?

Comment: A deprecation is not an error, it just mean that a dependency call deprecated code. You can just ignore it.

Comment: @A.L Yes you can ignore them but resolving the issues makes upgrading to a new major version easier.  I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the http-kernel component but rather a third party package which needs upgrading.  Could also be in the app itself.

Comment: You can try to upgrade only this package: `composer require symfony/error-handler`. Then check if you still see the deprecation message. Or update everything: `composer update` and check again.

Comment: @A.L this error is writing logs in each execution, then it's very dirty and not very comfortable to search some logs lines.